# Debug unload event in Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, onbeforeunload, onunload

I've set up a pretty simple proxy server with NodeJS. The code is fairly straight forward - the server takes a request from the client, send it to another server, and then pipe the response back to the client.

It works very well except under one scenario the website keeps reloading itself. I would like to debug what causes the reload and thus have setup two event listener breakpoints for the beforeunload event and unload event respectively. The two breakpoints were not triggered however.

Then I suddenly come across a piece of code which appears to be triggered every time when the page reload happens, the code snippet is as follows:

[image: extensions::unload_event]

Base on the commentary in the code, it appears to be a special unload event overriding the usual DOM upload. But on the call stack I don't see where does this get originated from. The code doesn't seem to be hosted on the server I'm firing the request to either, more like it is hosted locally.

So my question is:

1. Does anyone have any idea about this **extensions::unload_event** and the story behind it?
2. Do you have any advice on how should I proceed further in debugging the unexpected page reload?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This `unload_event` wrapper is no longer used in Chrome javascript shim layer for extensions ([deleted in 2014](https://codereview.chromium.org/312213002)). Try listening to the event via devtools (F12) - Sources panel - Event listener breakpoints - Load - [x] unload.

Comment: I see.

In fact my Chrome version is pretty old, as the dev machine I'm using is a controlled environment. Lemme see if I can proceed further with a newer version of Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Taking a closer look to the link you've attached, in fact unload_event.js was deleted from **chrome/renderer/resources/extensions/** but added back to **extensions/renderer/resources/**.

I've updated to a later version of Chrome (v43), which is released in around mid 2015, still not able to break on the beforeunload and unload even listener breakpoints.

Comment: 1. There's no [unload_event](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=%22unload_event%22+lang:js&sq=package:chromium&type=cs) in modern Chrome, 2. Now I remember I couldn't debug this event interactively as well, so I've used messaging to send stuff I needed to check into a background page. If you don't use an extension try `navigator.sendBeacon()`